# div triangle, canvas size

Tags: css, canvas, layout

[In this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/RobinsonUK/ryut6omv/4/) I've made a screen layout using divs and css, then added a canvas element inside each region with a black border so I can see its extent.

In this screenshot you can see the borders are correct for the 3 main elements of the left side-bar, but the top and bottom elements are cut off as if underneath the label div element.

[image]

I've given my canvas class the following properties:

```
.fitcanvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}
```

The intention is for the canvas to fill the area remaining (or 100% if there's nothing else in the parent).  I've tried putting it inside another div but cannot get it to work correctly.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle, you have given a 11% height to top and bottom css class, but to the remaining divs, it used .content which is 26% in height. This is making heights uneven. You can give 25% to all to make them of same height.

Your labels are overlapping your canvas area, because, you have given 100% height to canvas w.r.t its container, and the container includes label as well. Hence the problem. Please check [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hgd2ptL4/)

The css looks like:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

.left,
.right {
    float: left;
}

.left {
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}

.left .label-top,
.left .label-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.left .label-top {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.left .label-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.left .content,
.left .top,
.left .bottom {
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.left .top,
.left .bottom {
    height: 25%;
}

.left .content {
    height: 25%;
}

.colourred {
    background-color: red;
}

.colourgreen{
    background-color: green;
}

.colourblue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.right {
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}

.right::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.slider {

}

.fitcanvas {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black; 
    margin:1px;
}
```